# Is the basis of an eigen space unique?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question on a practice exam that asks for the basis of the eigenspaces of a matrix of a linear transformation. The transformation reflects a vector over the plane 
P: x+2y-z=0
The answer key has a formulaic approach, while I approached it more logically (at least I hope it was), but got a different answer, so I was wondering if there was more than one right answer, and if not, where my thinking is wrong.

I know that the transformation of a vector normal,n, to the plane would be
T(n)=-n 
(I believe if one were to draw out a plane with a normal vector this can be easily seen) meaning there is an eigenvalue of -1 and for a vector in the inside the plane, v, 
T(v)=v 
Since it is already on the plane. Therefore there is an eigenvalue of 1

Since the plane is in two dimensions I figured when the eigenvalue is 1 there must be two vectors orthogonal to each other, but both still in the plane.  I chose (1,0,1) and (-1,1,1). 
Likewise, when the eigenvalue is -1 there is a vector normal to the plane, I chose the normal of the plane (1,2,-1).
 Therefore since all vectors in the plane are a linear combination of the (1,0,1) and (-1,1,1) and all vectors normal to the plane can be spanned by (1,2,-1). I wrote the basis for the eigenspaces 1, and -1 to be

{(1,0,1),(-1,1,1)} and {(1, 2, -1)} respectively

while the answer is {(-2,1,0),(1,0,1)} and {-1,-2,1)} (which is the same as mine multiplied by -1)

Comment: This is just like asking if the basis of *any* subspace is unique...of course not.

Comment: Basis is not unique. A nonzero scalar can be applied to any basis element and you still have a basis

Comment: The basis for *any* space is never unique, be it an eigenspace or otherwise.  Take $\Bbb R^2$ for example., literally *any* two nonzero and nonparallel vectors act as a basis for the space.  The only exception to this would be redundant examples such as finding a basis for the vectorspace $\Bbb F_2=\{0,1\}$ over the field $\Bbb F_2$, to which the only basis is the only nonzero element, $1$.

Comment: Oh, I suppose that is quite obvious then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correct. You have find the eigenspaces of the linear transformation and a possible basis for these vector space. Obviously there are many ( infinitely many) other possibilities to chose a basis for these spaces.